# Strong and easy to remember password : Nonsense sentence or random chars?

Tags: security

I’ve been searching the web to have a secure and trust answer to that question: How can I know if my password is secure since I know a lot of websites do checks but none of them show the same result?

I [found this](https://xkcd.com/936/) which is really interesting and make me think that I have been wrong thinking a password with caps, numbers, symbols etc.. would be more secure.

Let's take an example with 2 passwords. The first (called password A) is a 9 char password which is not a word, does not contain a word, but just a random suite of caps, non caps, numbers & symbols. The second (called password B) is 4 random dictionary words put together (and which does not make sense/sentence) for 30 chars (only non caps and spaces).

On the [Password Meter](http://www.passwordmeter.com/):

- Password A = 71%
- Password B = 40%

On [How Secure is My Password](https://howsecureismypassword.net):

- Password A = 1 year.
- Password B = 154 octillion years.

Using [pwdtest](http://pwdtest.cases.lu):

- Password A got 118 years for a standard attack
- Password B got 7×10^24 millennia for a standard attack (assuming space is not a symbol).

So, all those sites give different results.

I went further and made a simple calculation:

Using a Stack Exchange question I took 95 as the number of possibilities for each char.

- For password A I got: `95^9 = 630249409724609000`
- For password B I used French & got 50 000 different words which is basically wrong as only small dictionaries got this number: `50000^4 = 6250000000000000000`.
- But using lower letters and the space I got: `27^30 = 8727963568087710000000000000000000000000000`

In 2 cases password B is much more stronger.

**Is a nonsense sentence more accurate as a password than a 10+ random Caps, lower, symbols etc which is hard to remember ?**

**SAME POST & ANSWER [HERE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase)**

Comment: It's not possible to estimate how secure your password is against a brute-force attack, without knowing how the password is stored. bcrypt with a cost factor of 12? Either password is going to be fine. Plain-text, which lots of websites do? Not secure no matter what you choose.

Comment: `In 2 cases password B is much more stronger.` if the attacker knows your password B is a set of 4 dictionary words, then correct calculation might be (size of dictionary)^4.  But if he doesn't know that then the attacker might have to try every possible connection of letters and numbers which would be far larger.  Unfortunately we live in a world where both the good guys and bad guys can read xkcd.

Comment: 50000^4 = 6250000000000000000.Even with a small dictionary, there are more possibilities, that's the strange thing.

Comment: You might get better results asking this question on our sister site, [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com), where similar discussions abound; e.g., [Best password strength checker](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/6499/34757), [Is there any point in using 'strong' passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/42134/34757) and [Are password complexity rules counterproductive?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/32222/34757)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your links. I went on https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase with your second one and this is exactly what I was looking for. Furthermore http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html confirmed what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

> So, all those sites give different results.

Ask five different people a question & you will get five different answers. It all boils down to the analytic methodology used & which you feel most comfortable benchmarking with.

Truth be told, I have been doing this type of work for 20+ on the web & hostly pretty much all online tools are designed to *always* make you think there is just one more thing you can do. Whether this be website speed tests, password checkers & many other tests I can barely keep track of.

The reality is you should just devise a password scheme—not necessarily a password—that works well for you and make sure to change it often. That scheme can be any dozens of things: A word, a phrase, a number, etc… But once you have a decent scheme just use that. And don’t worry too much.

Comment: According to http://reusablesec.blogspot.fr/2010/10/new-paper-on-password-security-metrics.html, change often my password isn't really useful. I've got scheme that led me to 16+ char password that are inhuman and "hard" to remember. And now I'm wondering if I can use a simple sentence (4-5 words) that has no sense

Comment: I understood that. My point is to know if it's better to continue having strong passwords (Caps, lower, symbols etc..) or change for few words which make it much more easier to remember !

Answer (score 1):

There is not one true way to measure password strength and there are TONS of factors that can go into password strength and more importantly password cracking.  In reality most websites just showing you a metric based on the rules they think are important (length, character classes, alternating classes, etc.).

The naive approach is pure brute force with no smarts.  Using this approach, in order to get the number of combinations, you would take the size of your alphabet raised to the power of the number of characters in the password.

However, most attackers aren't going to start guessing with `A`, then `B`, then `C`, and continuing.  They're going to use dictionary words.  Many attackers will use common "leet speak" character replacements, such as `$ = S` or `@ = A`.  Some will take dictionary words and then tack on random character sequences on the beginning or end of the word.

The other question is, what are you trying to measure?  How many combinations of passwords there are?  How long it will take to crack the password?  How long is very dependent on how the password is stored and the hardware that is doing the cracking.  I could pretty easily cut down the time brute force SHA1 password with a about $1000 USD in video card hardware.  You can imagine that professional hackers, corporations or governments could put large budgets towards hardware to make cracking very fast.

Really, the best password, is a long, truly random, passphrase built from the largest alphabet allowed by the site.  Using a password manager such as LastPass, 1Password or KeyPass can help you to generate and remember long passwords more easily.

Comment: I'm trying to get a masterpassword that would be really hard to crack. I'm currently using LastPass but I do not want to give my personal datas (and pwd are maybe the more important ones) to third party anymore. So, http://masterpasswordapp.com/ sounds a good idea but there is still the need of a "master" password. Furthermore I need one for GPG key and I guess it has to be really strong